# XCode6 binary invalid, no details from ITC support

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect, xcode6

My problem is that after migrating project to XCode6 I just can't submit my app - it's permanently becomes "invalid" - get status "invalid binary" after 10-30 minutes.

1. Before migration there was no any troubles
2. There is no code modifications since old XCode version (5.1)
3. Most frustrating is as other users I received email from ITC
   support, but it does not contains any details at all!

> ```
> iTunes Connect
>
>
> Dear XXX,
> The status for the following app has changed to Invalid Binary.
>
> App Name: XXX
> App Version Number: 2.0
> App SKU: XXX
> App Apple ID:XXX
> To make changes to this app, sign in to iTunes Connect and open the Manage Your Applications module.
>
> If you have any questions regarding your app, click Contact Us in iTunes Connect.
>
> Regards,
>
> The iTunes Store team
> ```

I wrote email to ITC support, but there is still no answer. Any suggestions? It's hard to me find any reason cos app successfully passes validation during upload.

Answer (score 1):

Large amount of tests lead me to next conclusion: one of third-party libraries (AppsFlyer) uses Advertising Identifier. I removed it from my app and for now all is ok. 
I think this problem is because of new builds/prereleases system - things which previously lead to warnings during validation/uploading now are not appear.
So annoying...

Answer (score 0):

I'm using several libraries which uses the AdvertiserId on several apps and the builds were submitted successfully.

When submitting the app, Apple ask 3 question about your app. The third is about using the Advertiser ID. Did you checked any of the options there? If not, You should....

Comment: The problem is that development of this app started by freelancers so we just didn't know that something used Advertiser ID. (More of that - even don't use, but just have selectors in static libraries.) We just continuing developing. Also biggest stupid thing that in old ITC there was warnings about something like that, but not in new one. Just silent invalidation **even without any** description about reason of invalidation. Also we prefer to not check this option when submitting app because we don't use any advertisements.